# Recruiting process time for assistant professor position in Japan?

Tags: assistant-professor, recruiting, japan

What time scale is typical for the evaluation of applications for an assistant professorship in Japan?

Comment: Like most other places, several months. If it's been over four months side you've heard from then, a note asking the status wouldn't be inappropriate.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the position, but couple of month is a reasonable scale. If you go through the first round (your resume is picked, which itself easily a month), you are contacted for an interview generally at least a month before the interview. However I have seen cases when it took months just to appoint an interview.

Note that many assistant professors are getting jobs by internal promotions and not through public advertisement.